# Fourier transformation to apply Gaussian Blur unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to blur my entire screen. 
My first attempt was to use a custom shader and kernel convolution. But this of course caused massive frame drop.
My second attempt is to use Fourier Transformation. Therefor my Plan is to take the image from RenderTexture source, using the "OnRenderImage"-function, and do the transformation and then save back.

```
void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination){}
```

But this means, as far as i could grasp it, copying the image from the graphics card memory to RAM, applying the transformations, and then copying it back.

Is this really the best way of doing it or should i try something else.

Best Wishes and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a built in blur effect in standard assets package, and this is probably the best way to do it:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-BlurOptimized.html

To use it simply import effects standard assets package, and add Blur script to your camera.

Behind the scenes, it actually will use `OnRenderImage`, but it does **not** mean copying the image from graphics memory to RAM, applying transformations and then copying it back.

The `RenderTexture` object represents a texture located in graphics card memory. You do not copy the pixels to RAM in order to manipulate it. Instead, manipulations on it are done in GPU via shader based filters, i.e. `Graphics.Blit(source, destination, someEffectMaterial);`.

See more info about postprocessing effects:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html